# How to get IDs from DIV without Javascript in Python Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to store in an arrays the IDs that have the same class name. When I try using pure python/selenium it fails and only works if I use javascript code.

This is my current code

```
html_content = """
<html>
<body>
<style>
.col-x-z.ab.def {
border: 4px outset orange;
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;
height:200px; width:400px; 
}
.portlet.box.blue {
border: 2px outset blue;
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div class="col-x-z ab def" id="sortable_portlets">
        <div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_1" col="1">
            <div id="353" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="355" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div class=" wqp"></div>            
        </div>  
    <div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_2" col="2">
            <div id="473" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="475" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div class=" wqp"></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
"""

from selenium import webdriver

driver_path="/my/path/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))

ids_arr = driver.execute_script('var coll = document.getElementsByClassName(" portlet box blue"), ids = [], i = 0; while( coll[ i ] ) { ids.push( coll[ i++ ].id ) };return ids;')

>>> ids_arr
['353', '355', '473', '475']
```

As you can see, with javascript I get the 4 IDs stored within `ids_arr`.

But if I try like this I get error:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_class_name(" portlet box blue")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/myUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
File "/home/myUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "/home/myUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/myUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
(Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)
```

What is wrong and how to make it work without javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your code is

```
document.getElementsByClassName(" portlet box blue")
```

which is searching for elements by class name but you have provided 3 class names: "portlet", "box", and "blue" to the method. That's why you are getting the message, `invalid selector`. You would have to choose only one for the method to succeed... or you could use a CSS selector, `.portlet.box.blue`, to get all three. NOTE: `.` in the CSS selector indicates classname.

I'm not sure why you are using JS at all... you don't need to.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".portlet.box.blue")
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute("id"))
```

or if you want the element IDs in an array, you can do

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".portlet.box.blue")
ids = []
for element in elements:
    ids.append(element.get_attribute("id"))
print(ids)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much. It works perfect. I've tried with JS because I wasn't able to get it working. Is better, clearest and simplest with pure Python/Selenium.